# Creating managed RealmList outside RealmObject

Tags: java, realm, realm-list

In my app, I have a method that accepts an `ArrayList` of ID's and returns a `RealmList` of Machines belonging to these IDs.

```
public RealmList<Machine> getMachinesById(ArrayList<Long> machineIds) {
    RealmList<Machine> machines = new RealmList<Machine>();
    for (int i = 0; i < machineIds.size(); i++){
        Machine m = getMachineById(machineIds.get(i));
        if (m != null) {
            machines.add(m);
        }
    }
    return machines;
}
```

*The `getMachineById()` function just finds the correct machine for a specific id.*

I want to filter this output some more, however, when I try to get the `RealmQuery` by doing `.where()`, I get an Exception telling me I should put this `RealmList` in 'managed mode'.

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: This method is only available in managed mode
                                                 at io.realm.RealmList.where(RealmList.java:425)
```

I'm aware that I get this error because this list is standalone, and not managed by Realm.

It is probably important to add that this function will be called quite a lot, since it is triggered every time some list in my app refreshes. This would mean that (if possible) every time I'm creating a new managed RealmList.

My questions:

- Is there any way to let this RealmList be managed by Realm?
- If this is possible, is it a problem that this function is being called pretty often
- Is there any other (preferred) way to achieve this (List of IDs > RealmResults/RealmQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to let this RealmList be managed by Realm?

Yes. There is. But the point of having `RealmList` is it should be a field of an `RealmObjects`. eg.:

```
public class Factory {
    RealmList<Machine> machineList;
    // setter & getters
}

Factory factory = new Factory();
RealmList<Machine> machineList = new RealmList<>();
// Add something to the list
factory.setMachines(machineList);
realm.beginTransaction();
Factory managedFactory = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(factory);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Managed means it has be persisted Realm.

> If this is possible, is it a problem that this function is being called pretty often

Depends, if you don't need to persist them again, see answer 3.

> Is there any other (preferred) way to achieve this (List of IDs > RealmResults/RealmQuery)

In your case, maybe you can use `ReaulResults` instead? eg.:

```
RealmQuery<Machine> query = realm.where(Machine.class);
for (int i = 0; i < machineIds.size(); i++){
    if (i != 0) query = query.or();
    query = query.equalTo("id", machineIds.get(i));
}
RealmResults<Machine> machines = query.findAll();
```

Comment: Since the `Machine` objects are persisted already, and there is no need to persist this `RealmList` on its own, it is preferred to use RealmResults? In a more general sense: It is a better pattern to use RealmResults when communicating a not-to-be-persisted subset of any object set?

Comment: Yeah, so you might need the `RealmQuery.or()` as i show in the example. Also, it is not the ideal way for your use case, we had an feature request for that https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/841