# Realm Error: This method is only available in managed mode

Tags: java, android, realm

When I install my app for first time on my phone, the app crashes because of the Realm error: `This method is only available in managed mode` which I really don't understand much of

This happends when I try to get a sorted list of `ListItem` in the class `Shoplist`

```
public class Shoplist extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

private RealmList<ListItem> itemList;   //ListItem extends `RealmObject`

@Ignore
private Realm realm;

@PrimaryKey
private long id;

public Shoplist() {

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

public RealmList<ListItem> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

 public List<ListItem> getItems(String listOrder) {

    RealmResults<ListItem> realmResults;

    switch (listOrder) {
        case PrefActivity.ASCENDING:
            realmResults = getItemList().where().findAll(); // this crashes!
            break;

        case PrefActivity.DESCENDING:
            realmResults = getItemList().where().findAllSorted(ListItem.TIME_STAMP, Sort.DESCENDING);
            break;
    }

    return realmResults;
   }
}
```

A Shoplist object is created like this in a class called `RealmService`

```
public Shoplist createShoplist(String title) {

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    Shoplist shoplist = new Shoplist(new RealmList<ListItem>(), title);
    realm.copyToRealm(shoplist);
    realm.commitTransaction();

    return shoplist;

}
```

**STATS:**

Realm Gradle Plugin: 2.3.1

Gradle Plugin: 2.2.3

Compile version: 25

Android Studio version: 2.2.3

Test phone: Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162444/creating-managed-realmlist-outside-realmobject) may help you with your probelm

Comment: this answer may help you in your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162444/creating-managed-realmlist-outside-realmobject

Comment: You really should close your realm instance. Also, you really should not give your model class a realm instance.

Comment: @TimCastelijns According to Realm documentation a realm instance shall be closed when the activity using Realm is destroyed. So I close my realm when `onDestroy()` is called of that Activity which is using Realm.


Should I not give it a @Ignore private Realm realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need work with [*managed object*](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#what-is-the-difference-between-a-normal-java-object-and-a-realm-object). Your error happen when `Shoplist` object created with `new` operator - **it's not managed object**.

You need to wrap instance of `Shoplist` to Realm:

```
public Shoplist createShoplist(String title) {

     realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
     realm.beginTransaction();

     Shoplist shoplist = realm.createObject(Shoplist.class)
     shoplist.setTitle(title);

     realm.copyToRealm(shoplist);
     realm.commitTransaction();

     return shoplist;
}
```

Comment: I just edited my question. Please take a look at the bottom of it. Is because I do that way?

Comment: Aha allright! Everyone keeps saying because its not managed object but no one explained how an unmanaged vs managed looks like, your answer did!

Comment: But using this way it won't have `Shoplist`to contain a `@primaryKey`, so I removed it and using this call `realm.createObject(Shoplist.class, System.currentTimeMillis());`

But how can I then retrive the id of the created object of `Shoplist` then? where is it stored

Comment: @Muddz, in your case primary key stored at `private long id` field which anotated as `@PrimaryKey`. You should create `long getId()` method if you wish to take this